# ES6 pattern using bind in React apps

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I notice that in a lot of React code examples you'll see something like the following:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.someMethod = this.someMethod.bind(this);
  }

  someMethod() {

  }

  <Bar doSomething={this.someMethod} />
}
```

Other examples I see do the following:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  someMethod() {

  }

  <Bar doSomething={this.someMethod} />
}
```

Do both of these patterns achieve the same result? Is there a downside to using one vs the other?

Comment: I think you meant in your constructor `this.someMethod = this.someMethod.bind(this);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it depends on what the method does. If the method references `this` in reference to the component it should be bound in the constructor, so that the lexical context will be correct. Otherwise that method will raise errors.

If the method is not referencing `this` then there is no need to bind the method.

Alternatively, you can use this pattern:

```
someMethod = () => {}
```

Since fat arrow functions don't have a lexical `this`